# How to clear the server side validation error message if the user enters the correct value?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, html

I have a form and fields are `Name, Mobile, Email and Message`. I am using JQuery validation. There is no issue with Jquery validation. I am getting some issue on server side validation message.

I am submitting the form using AJAX and display the server error message using JSON response.

It is also working perfectly but the issue is I am not able to clear the server side error message when the user enters the value.

If the `Name` field is empty then it's displaying the error message but after entering the name it's still displaying the error message.

Check when Name field is empty and server-side validation displaying.

[image]

After enters the name it's still showing an error message.

[image]

Would you help me out on this issue?

**AJAX**

```
$("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            mobileno:{
                required:true,
                minlength:10,
                maxlength:10,
                number: true
            },
            email:{
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
             message:{
                minlength:10
            }
        },  
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).removeClass("error");
        },   
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            //form.submit();
            $.ajax({
            url: "process.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data); 
             if (response.error_no === '1'){
                $('#errorname').html(response.error);
             }
             else if (response.error_no === '2'){
                $('#errorMobile').html(response.error);
             }
             else if(response.error_no === '3'){
                  $('#errorEmail').html(response.error);
             }
             else if(response.error_no === '4'){
              alert(response.error);
             }
             else{
                      $("#popup_verify-1").hide(); 
                      $("#popup_success-1").show(); 
                      $('#form')[0].reset();     
                     }
                  },
                  error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                  }
                }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
                }
    });
```

**Process.php**

```
$name=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
      $mobileno=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mobileno']));
      $email=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
      $message=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['message']));
      $ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//ip address

  if($name =="") {
    $errorMsg[]=  "You did not enter a name.";
    $code= "1" ;
    }
  elseif($mobileno == "") {
    $errorMsg[]=  "Please enter number.";
    $code= "2";
  }
  elseif(is_numeric(trim($mobileno)) == false){
    $errorMsg[]=  "Please enter numeric value.";
    $code= "2";
  }elseif(strlen($mobileno)<10){
    $errorMsg[]=  "Number should be ten digits.";
    $code= "2";
  }elseif($email == ""){
    $errorMsg[]=  "You did not enter a email.";
    $code= "3";
} //check for valid email 
elseif(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)){
  $errorMsg[]= 'You did not enter a valid email.';
  $code= "3";
}

else{
       $sql="INSERT INTO contactus (name, mobileno, email, message, date_of_contact,ipaddress) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)";
       if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
          $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $mobileno, $email, $message, $currentdate, $ipaddress);
          $stmt->execute(); 
          $errorMsg[]=1;
       }
       else{
      $code= "4";
        $errorMsg[]='Poor Network Connection';
       }
        $stmt->close();
       $conn->close();
    }

    $respnonse['error_no']=$code;
    $respnonse['error']=$errorMsg;
  echo json_encode($respnonse);
```

Comment: Let me know if require the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually still client side. The data you are returning is correct, without errors, but you are not clearing your errors from the page.

So use something like this to clear the errors:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data); 

var hasError = false;
if (response.error_no === '1') {
    $('#errorname').html(response.error);
    hasError = true;
} else {
    $('#errorname').html('');
}

if (!hasError) {
    alert('Success, no errors!');
}
```

Comment: give me some time to check. Where I have to use $('#errorname').html(''); because I have nested if conditon

Comment: You might need to separate them into something like: if (error) { showError } else { removeError } if (error2) { showError } else { removeError }

Comment: And what about the last else condition?

Comment: @user9437856 I've updated my answer with a check to see if any error occurs. Use it as your last else condition.

Comment: @user9437856 If I helped you out could you please accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry to say, It's not helped me.